# Alert Box works in one way not in other Way

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, syntax

When I write this Piece of code the Alert Box do not appear -

```
$(document).ready(function() {
alert('Welcome to StarTrackr! Now no longer under police
investigation!);
});
```

But when I write this piece of Code the Alert box appears =

```
$(function() {
alert('Ready to do your bidding!');
});
```

What could be the reason?

Comment: Don’t you have a text editor with syntax highlighting? Are you blindly writing and executing code without even watching for errors in the browser console? You’ve got a line break within a string and you’re not even closing the string.

Comment: You could have said it politely also. Everyone is a beginner some day before he becomes a PRO.

Comment: By the way thank you so much. That as indeed helpful.

Comment: You missing last single quote at alert - first code  block.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to close the string in your first alert box. You can see the syntax is highlighting the entire section.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
alert('Welcome to StarTrackr! Now no longer under police investigation!');
});
```

Comment: Thank you so much. I am quite new to the world of coding so they may appear minor error, but they are majors for me. thank you so much.

Comment: What is the process of watching error in Browser Console - "watching for errors in the browser console"

Comment: @Champion [How to open the JavaScript console in different browsers?](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/q/8525)

Comment: The issue you have returns a 'HTMLEmail.html:5 Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token' in the console which gives you the page and line number of the error. Once you have that information it is easy to find any issue you may have.

Also, bit harsh to down vote someone for this post. God forbid someone new starts having issues.

Comment: Actually I was learning from this Book - Castledine E. Sharkie C. - jQuery. Novice to Ninja 2nd Edition - 2012
And I just Copy and pasted from there, probably they had this minor typographical mistake. Thank you so much, that was indeed helpful. I have noted these points. Thanks again :)